# Deselect range selector in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have implemented a custom date range functionality in highcharts where I can specify from and to dates and hit refresh to redraw the chart. In this case I want to deselect the filters like 1m, 6m, ytd etc so that none of the filters should be highlighted.

I tried few options like below but none of seems to be working.

```
  chart.rangeSelector({ selected: 0 });

  chart.rangeSelector({ selected: null });

  chart.rangeSelector({ selected: "" });
```

Could someone help me on this please?

P.S - I'm not using the date range option that comes inbuilt with highcharts.

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live demo  ?